# Sending a email with powershell

Tags: email, powershell

I want to send a email with powershell. The script works fine if I type my credential in manualy. But I want to give the credential parameters within the script. My script looks like this:

```
$From = "test@yahoo.de"
$To = "test2@yahoo.de"
$Cc = "test@yahoo.de"
$Attachment = "C:\Users\test\test\test.ini"
$Subject = "Email Subject"
$Body = "Insert body text here"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject `
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
-Credential ( 
$MyClearTextUsername=’test@yahoo.de’
$MyClearTextPassword=’test123’

$SecurePassword=Convertto-SecureString –String $MyClearTextPassword –AsPlainText –force

$MyCredentials=New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $MyClearTextPassword,$SecurePassword) -Attachments $Attachment
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can create a credentials object:

```
$cred = ([pscredential]::new('test@yahoo.de',(ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'test123' -AsPlainText -Force)))
```

so in your case use:

```
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject `
  -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl `
  -Credential $cred -Attachments $Attachment
```

I see no point in trying to fit that into the `Send-MailMessage`, just create it before and reference it. easier to read.

Comment: no problem, if the answer helped you, mark it as an answer ;) @Tibi

Comment: Marked ! Wouldn't let me until now. You answered too quickley :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Office365 to send email, you might want to try this:

```
# Sending an email from PowerShell 5.1 script through outlook.office365.com
#
# 1. Create an encrypted password file
#   PS > Read-Host -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File -FilePath <passwordfile>
#   This will prompt you for a password, encrypt and save in <passwordfile>
# 2. Obtain Outlook Office365 SMTP server name.
#   Go to your ISP and find the value of the MX record. For example <yourdomain>.mail.protection.outlook.com
# 3. If after running the script you get this error:
#   Send-MailMessage : Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.606 Access denied, banned sending IP [X.X.X.X].
#   You will need to delist your IP by going here: https://sender.office.com/
#   Note:  Removing you IP from the block list could take up to 30 minutes.
#
$User = "<SMPT loging username>"
$PasswordFile = "<passwordfile>"
$SMTPCredentials=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString)
$EmailTo = "<to email address>"
$EmailFrom = "<from email address>"
$Subject = "<email subject>" 
$Body = "<email body>" 
$SMTPServer = "<Outlook STMP Server from MX record>"
Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port 25 -Credential $SMTPCredentials -UseSsl
```